# Add write permission and keep gid

Tags: chmod

Here is the setup:

- I have a user called `git` with a `umask` of `022`.
- `git` adds files and folders into a folder called `htdocs`.
- `htdocs` has `drwxr-srx` permissions (gid set) and is owned by `git:apache`
- Created files and folders in `htdocs` have `-rw-r--r--` (644) and `drwxr-srx` (2775)

Sometimes I need to give Apache write permissions to a folder:

```
chmod g+w some-folder
```

The problem is that it loses the gid, so instead of:

```
drwxrwsr-x
```

I get:

```
drwxrwxr-x
```

When I try to add the gid back:

```
chmod g+s some-folder
```

It doesn't do anything. `some-folder` still only has 755 permissions.

I also tried manually setting it to 2755:

```
chmod 2755 some-folder
```

With no luck.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can keep the gid set?

### Update

After a few additional hours of research and seeing that other users had the same issue, [@twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg) nailed the only two options available. I decided to create a new group and place both git and apache in it. Now that git belongs to that group, the gid remains set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man 2 chmod` has this to say:

```
    If the calling process is not privileged  (Linux:  does  not  have  the
    CAP_FSETID  capability),  and  the group of the file does not match the
    effective group ID of the process or one  of  its  supplementary  group
    IDs,  the  S_ISGID  bit  will be turned off, but this will not cause an
    error to be returned.
```

I am guessing that `git` is not in the `apache` group, so when `git` changes the mode on the directory, the setgid bit is automatically cleared. You can either add `git` to the `apache` group, or use a privileged account to do the `chmod`.

Comment: In this particular instance I can't use a privileged account as this is run through a hook and I would prefer not to add `git` to `apache` for just this one-off case. It seems that there should be a way to add permissions without it automatically clearing (one of the reasons the gid is set in the parent `htdocs` folder).

Comment: Well, yes, there is. The "way to add permissions without it automatically clearing" is to be aware of the semantics, and either arrange for the process doing `chmod()` to be a privileged process, or to have the `gid` in question be the EGID or a supplemental GID for that process - i.e. put `git` in the `apache` group, or do the `chmod` with `root` or another privileged process...

Comment: Yup, after some more research, that really does seem to be my only two options :) I added an update to my question.